# Unable to create user in firebase flask pyrebase

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, api

I am using pyrebase for calling firebase APIs in python/flask. I am able to sign in with but unable to create a new user. Here is my code for creating new user.

```
@app.route('/api/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        print(email)
        print(password)
        if email is None or password is None:
            msg = 'Error missing email or password'
        try:
            user = auth.create_user(
                email=email,
                password=password
            )
            print(user)
            msg = f'Successfully created user {user.uid}'
        except:
            msg = 'There was an error creating user'
    return render_template("result.html", msg=msg)
```

try is not executed and I got except message on screen. I have searched on google, and found nothing helpful. Why auth.create is not creating a new user. There is no user in firebase.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? Can you post?

Comment: not any error. after entering in try block, it prints whatever is before calling create_user function and after then goes into except block, mean that user is not being created. I am printing user after calling the create user function as you can see in the above code, but it does not execute that line. On the webpage this message is printed "'There was an error creating user'"

Comment: Go ahead and pull your auth.create_user call outside of your try block to see what error is being returned and give us that information.

Comment: I used this function for creating user. https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#manage-users